# Searching Cell Value in Entire work Book and delete the containg row form each worksheet Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I have Excel Work book with multiple sheets where two worksheets are master
list, in which one of the sheets Assetmaster, and second is Masterlist. Now
the Masterlist has all the records where as the Assetmaster has only portion
of Masterlist.
Now I have form with list box displaying the records from Assetmaster. I can
select record by selecting it. From here I want to delete the selected record
from both the Excel worksheet, Assetmaster and Masterlist.

Not necessarily both are in same row in respective worksheet.

---

Following code delete the same row number in both worksheets:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Sheets("assetmaster").Select
  ListBox1.RowSource = "A2:I500"
  Range("A2").Select
  End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
  riga = ListBox1.ListIndex + 2
  'Cells(riga, 1).Activate
  testo = ListBox1
  'If testo <> "" Then
  'End If

  TextBox1.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & riga)

  End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the Tool " & ActiveCell.Value & "?  Note Tools will be deleted form the masterlist as well if you need please add again in master list using add toolutility " _
      & Chr(10), _
      vbYesNo, Title:="Tool Deletion")
  If response = vbNo Then
  Exit Sub
  Else
  End If

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rs As Worksheet
  Dim Rand As Long

  Set ws = Worksheets("assetmaster")
  Set rs = Worksheets("masterlist")
  rs.Unprotect
  ws.Unprotect
  Rand = ListBox1.ListIndex + 2
  'ws.Rows(Rand) = ""
  'rs.Rows(Rand) = ""
  rs.Rows(Rand).Delete
  ws.Rows(Rand).Delete

  ' Dim tbmno As String
  ' tbmno = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rand)

  rs.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
  ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
  ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=False
  ActiveWorkbook.Save

  End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you have to look up the record in the Masterlist. For this you better have some unique id for your records. Then iterate over all records in Masterlist, or use vlookup().

Comment: Yes I do have unique ID , The cloumn G contains the Unique ID only , so selecting the list i have selected the unique ID in one sheet now i need to delete the same row in bith the seet ,  But unable to fiugure out, and Vlookup method doesnot work well . Will be nice if you can share the code you you intend to do it . it will be great help

Comment: i figured it out thanks out for help

Answer (score 0):

If you can get unique ID and the data are in a tabular form, i would suggest to use ADO. It is the simplest and quickest way than any Excel function ;)
Please, have a look here:
[How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)
[How To Invoke a Parameterized ADO Query Using VBA/C++/Java](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181734/en)

Sql command should looks like:

```
DELETE *
FROM [MasterList$]
WHERE [UniqueID] = [ValueFromList]

DELETE *
FROM [Assetmaster$]
WHERE [UniqueID] = [ValueFromList]
```

If you get stuck, please let me know ;)